# Passing map type argument in function in Erlang complains error

Tags: erlang, erlang-shell

Here's my code snippet.

```
%% test.erl
-export([count_characters/1]).

count_characters(Str) ->
  count_characters(Str, #{}).

count_characters([H|T], #{H := N} = X) ->
  count_characters(T, X#{H := N+1});
count_characters([H|T], X) ->
  count_characters(T, X#{H => 1});
count_characters([], X) ->
  X.

%% ErShell
1> c(test).
test.erl:19: illegal use of variable 'H' in map
test.erl:20: illegal use of variable 'H' in map
test.erl:20: variable 'N' is unbound
test.erl:22: illegal use of variable 'H' in map
error
```

I just don't know why it complains such error, since the following code just worked out fine:

```
%% test2.erl
birthday(#{age := N} = Person) ->
    Person#{age := N+1}.

%% ErShell
1> c(test2).
2> test2:birthday(#{age => 333}).
#{age => 334}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason is simple: map hasn't been fully implemented yet. Take a look at: http://learnyousomeerlang.com/maps

Also, you might think of alternative implementations, using the stuff that's already possible with maps:

```
count_characters(Str) -> count_characters(Str, #{}).

count_characters([H|T], Map) ->
    N = maps:get(H, Map, 0),
    count_characters(T, maps:put(H, N + 1, Map));
count_characters([], Map) -> Map.
```

Comment: Just as a add-on: you've probably found your code in Joe's Programming Erlang, 2nd ed, eh? It's on the errata-list already. It will work, at some time in the future.

Answer (score 0):

As of today (2021), the feature is still not implemented.
However, for larger keys it is recommended to use the `update` function for reasons of efficiency:

```
count_characters([H|T], Map) ->
    case N = maps:get(H, Map, 0) of
       0 -> count_chars(T, Map#{H => 1});
       _ -> count_chars(T, Map#{H := N+1}) % update function maps:udpate(...)
    end;
```